# Parsing values from complex table using JSoup

Tags: java, web-scraping, html-table, jsoup, html-parsing

I have a table with the following html:

```
<TABLE class=data-table cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0>
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD colSpan=4><A id=accounting name=accounting></A>
      <H3>Accounting</H3></TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TH class=data-tablehd align=left>FORM NO.</TH>
    <TH class=data-tablehd align=left>TITLE</TH>
    <TH class=data-tablehd align=right>Microsoft</TH>
    <TH class=data-tablehd align=right>Acrobat</TH></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD><A id=1008ft name=1008ft>SF 1008-FT</A></TD>
    <TD>Work for Others Funding Transfer Between Projects for an Agreement</TD>
    <TD align=right><A 
      href="https://someurl1" 
      target=top>MS Word</A></TD>
    <TD align=right><A 
      href="https://someurl2" 
      target=top>PDF </A></TD></TR>
...
```

I need to parse the `<TR>` data getting something like

```
SF 1008-FT, Work for Others ... an Agreement, https://someurl1, https://someurl2
```

I have tried using the following code:

```
    URL formURL = new URL("http://urlToParse");
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(formURL, 3000);

    Element table = doc.select("TABLE[class = data-table]").first();
    Iterator<Element> ite = table.select("td[colSpan=4]").iterator();

    while(ite.next() != null) {
        System.out.println(ite.next().text());
    }
```

However this only returns the "back to Top" and some different headings located throughout the table.

Can someone help me write the correct JSoup code to parse the information I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution with some small modification to a similar thread. The code that provides the solution is given below:

```
for (Element table : doc.select("table")) {
        for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
            Elements tds = row.select("td");
            formNumber = tds.get(0).text();
            title = tds.get(1).text();
            link1 = tds.get(2).select("a[href]").attr("href");
            link2 = tds.get(3).select("a[href]").attr("href");
            }
}
```

Comment: I think it will give you back also the world "Accounting". But I'm glad you found the solution.

Answer (score 3):

I have not time to test, but you can use something like this:

```
        Element table = doc.select("TABLE[class = data-table]").first();
        Elements rows = table.select("tr");

        for (Element td: rows.get(2).children()) {
            System.out.println(td.text());
        }
```

You get the children of the 3rd row of the table.