# Input a generated file back into the program

Tags: java, database, swing, csv, file-io

I'm making a application in which I need to insert values from a html table to a database. I've figured its possible by first converting the html table to a .csv and then importing from csv to a database is simple.

I found a written script online that converts the html table into a csv. [TableToCSV](http://wush.net/svn/mindprod/com/mindprod/csv/TableToCSV.java)

However, it has a limitation that it produces the output file .csv in the same folder as, where user selects the .html file. And hence I do not know how to give this newly generated csv file to my BufferedReader.

```
 final JFileChooser  fileDialog = new JFileChooser();
JButton btnInputFile = new JButton("Input File");
btnInputFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        int returnVal = fileDialog.showOpenDialog(rootPane);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
           java.io.File file = fileDialog.getSelectedFile();

           String name = file.getName();
           name = name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf("."));
           name += ".html";
           File newFile = new File(file.getParentFile(), name);
           if (file.renameTo(newFile)) {
               try {
                TableToCSV tableToCSV = new TableToCSV(newFile, ',', '\"', '#', CSV.UTF8Charset );
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           }

           try
           {
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(newFile));
            String line;

            while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                String[]value = line.split(",");
                String sql = "INSERT into main ( , Ticket #, Status, Priority, Department, Account Name) "
                 + "values ('"+value[0]+"','"+value[1]+"','"+value[2]+"','"+value[3]+"','"+value[4]+"','"+value[5]+"')";

                 PreparedStatement pst = DatabaseConnection.ConnectDB().prepareStatement(sql);
                 pst.executeUpdate();

            }
            br.close();

           }

           catch(Exception e)
           {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
           }

        }

    }
});
btnInputFile.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Symbol", Font.BOLD, 15));
btnInputFile.setBounds(34, 31, 122, 51);
getContentPane().add(btnInputFile);
```

As you can see, entering newFile inside BufferedReader is not correct. Please suggest a way to either edit the TableToCSV file such that I can't bring the output file into a location where I can further put it in my BufferedReader.

Comment: Have you investigated the [JSoup API](http://jsoup.org) It provides functionality for parsing html. A similar question is posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910291/parsing-values-from-complex-table-using-jsoup/19933593#19933593)

Comment: Have you looked into using some kind of persistence API?

Answer (score 1):

> I found a written script online that converts the html table into a csv. TableToCSV
>
> However, it has a limitation that it produces the output file .csv in the same folder

From what I know of Roedy Green (who wrote that code), I expect the source code is intended to *teach you how* to do something.  That 'something' is 'create a CSV'.  The idea is you are free to take it and alter it to the point where it works for your use-case.  In fact, the license is stated at the top:

> This software may be copied and used freely for ***any purpose but military.***

I'd suggest altering the method signature to accept **2 files** where one is the existing input file, and the 2nd is the intended **output file** (and don't use it in your ICBM).