# Control output file of a script

Tags: java, file, csv, file-io

In continuation from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22277551/input-a-generated-file-back-into-the-program) question.

I need help in making my TableToCSV (function that converts .html table to csv), render the code to a database, rather than a .csv. I created a BufferedReader, which converts .csv to database, but I can't get the 2 to connect. Please make the output file of TableToCSV go into my bufferedreader.

TableToCSV

```
 * [TableToCSV.java]
 *
 * Summary: Extracts rows in CSV tables to CSV form. Extracts data from all tables in the input. Output in xxx.csv.
 *
 * Copyright: (c) 2011-2014 Roedy Green, Canadian Mind Products, http://mindprod.com
 *
 * Licence: This software may be copied and used freely for any purpose but military.
 *          http://mindprod.com/contact/nonmil.html
 *
 * Requires: JDK 1.6+
 *
 * Created with: JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA IDE http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/
 *
 * Version History:
 *  1.0 2011-01-23 initial version.
 *  1.1 2011-01-25 allow you to specify encoding
 */
package com.mindprod.csv;

import com.mindprod.common11.Misc;
import com.mindprod.entities.DeEntifyStrings;
import com.mindprod.hunkio.HunkIO;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import static java.lang.System.err;
import static java.lang.System.out;

/**
 * Extracts rows in CSV tables to CSV form. Extracts data from all tables in the input. Output in xxx.csv.
 * <p/>
 * Use: java.exe com.mindprod.TableToCSV xxxx.html
 * It also strips tags and converts entities back to UTF-8 characters.
 *
 * @author Roedy Green, Canadian Mind Products
 * @version 1.1 2011-01-25 allow you to specify encoding
 * @since 2011-01-23
 */
public final class TableToCSV

{
// ------------------------------ CONSTANTS ------------------------------

/**
 * how to use the command line
 */
private static final String USAGE = "TableToCSV needs the name of an HTML file on the commandline, " +
                                    "nothing else. Output will be in xxx.csv.";

// -------------------------- PUBLIC INSTANCE  METHODS --------------------------

/**
 * Constructor to convert an HTML table to CSV. Strips out entities and tags.
 *
 * @param file          CSV file to be packed to remove excess space and quotes.
 * @param separatorChar field separator character, usually ',' in North America,
 *                      ';' in Europe and sometimes '\t' for
 *                      tab for the output file.  It is tab for the input file.
 *                      Note this is a 'char' not a "string".
 * @param quoteChar     character used to quote fields containing awkward chars.
 * @param commentChar   character to treat as comments.
 * @param encoding      encoding of the input and output file.
 *
 * @throws java.io.IOException if problems reading/writing file
 */
@SuppressWarnings({ "WeakerAccess" })
public TableToCSV( final File file, final char separatorChar, final char quoteChar, final char commentChar,
                   final Charset encoding ) throws IOException
    {
    String outFilename = Misc.getCanOrAbsPath( file );
    outFilename = outFilename.substring( 0, outFilename.length() - 5 ) + ".csv";
    final File outFile = new File( outFilename );
    // writer, quoteLevel, separatorChar, quoteChar, commentChar, trim
    final PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(
            outFile ), 32768 ), encoding ) );
    final CSVWriter w = new CSVWriter( pw, 0 /* minimal  */, separatorChar, quoteChar, commentChar, true );
    // read the entire html file into RAM.
    String big = HunkIO.readEntireFile( file, encoding );
    int from = 0;
    // our parser is forgiving, works even if </td> </tr> missing.
    while ( true )
        {
        // find <tr
        final int trStart = big.indexOf( "<tr", from );
        if ( trStart < 0 )
            {
            break;
            }
        from = trStart + 3;
        final int trEnd = big.indexOf( '>', from );
        if ( trEnd < 0 )
            {
            break;
            }
        while ( true )
            {
            // search for <td>...</td>
            final int tdStart = big.indexOf( "<td", from );
            if ( tdStart < 0 )
                {
                break;
                }
            from = tdStart + 3;
            final int tdEnd = big.indexOf( '>', from );
            if ( tdEnd < 0 )
                {
                break;
                }
            from = tdEnd + 1;
            final int startField = tdEnd + 1;
            final int slashTdStart = big.indexOf( "</td", from );
            final int lookaheadTd = big.indexOf( "<td", from );
            final int lookaheadSlashTr = big.indexOf( "</tr", from );
            final int lookaheadTr = big.indexOf( "<tr", from );
            int endField = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            if ( slashTdStart >= 0 && slashTdStart < endField )
                {
                endField = slashTdStart;
                }
            if ( lookaheadTd >= 0 && lookaheadTd < endField )
                {
                endField = lookaheadTd;
                }
            if ( lookaheadSlashTr >= 0 && lookaheadSlashTr < endField )
                {
                endField = lookaheadSlashTr;
                }
            if ( lookaheadTr >= 0 && lookaheadTr < endField )
                {
                endField = lookaheadTr;
                }
            if ( endField == Integer.MAX_VALUE )
                {
                break;
                }
            from = endField + 3;
            final int slashTdEnd = big.indexOf( '>', from );
            if ( slashTdEnd < 0 )
                {
                break;
                }
            String field = big.substring( startField, endField );
            field = DeEntifyStrings.flattenHTML( field, ' ' );
            w.put( field );
            from = slashTdEnd + 1;
            final int lookTd = big.indexOf( "<td", from );
            final int lookTr = big.indexOf( "<tr", from );
            if ( lookTr >= 0 && lookTr < lookTd || lookTd < 0 )
                {
                break;
                }
            }
        w.nl();
        }
    out.println( w.getLineCount() + " rows extracted from table to csv" );
    w.close();
    }

// --------------------------- main() method ---------------------------

/**
 * Simple command line interface to TableToCSV. Converts one  HTML file to a CSV file, extracting tables,
 * with entities stripped.
 * Must have extension .html <br> Use java com.mindprod.TableToCSV somefile.html .  You can use TableToCSV
 * constructor
 * in your own programs.
 *
 * @param args name of csv file to remove excess quotes and space
 */
public static void main( String[] args )
    {
    if ( args.length != 1 )
        {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( USAGE );
        }
    String filename = args[ 0 ];
    if ( !filename.endsWith( ".html" ) )
        {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Bad Extension. Input must be a .html file.\n" + USAGE );
        }
    final File file = new File( filename );

    try
        {
        // file, separatorChar, quoteChar, commentChar, encoding
        new TableToCSV( file, ',', '\"', '#', CSV.UTF8Charset );
        }
    catch ( IOException e )
        {
        err.println();
        e.printStackTrace( err );
        err.println( "CSVToTable failed to export" + Misc.getCanOrAbsPath( file ) );
        err.println();
        }
    }// end main
}
```

And here is my BufferedReader

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(newFile));
        String line;

        while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
        {
            String[]value = line.split(",");
            String sql = "INSERT into main ( , Ticket #, Status, Priority, Department, Account Name) "
             + "values ('"+value[0]+"','"+value[1]+"','"+value[2]+"','"+value[3]+"','"+value[4]+"','"+value[5]+"')";

             PreparedStatement pst = DatabaseConnection.ConnectDB().prepareStatement(sql);
             pst.executeUpdate();

        }
        br.close();

       }

       catch(Exception e)
       {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
       }

    }

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you test your database codes?  does it work? (Hint: your sql statement is wrong).  Is it auto-commit on?  If not, aren't you suppose to close() the statement/connection?

I would factor the code and move the sql statement out and creation of prepared statement out side of the loop:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO MAIN(\"Ticket #\", \"Status\", \"Priority\", \"Department\", \"Account Name\") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
PreparedStatement pst = DatabaseConnection.ConnectDB().prepareStatement(sql);
```

Then inside your while loop you just set the the object before execute.

```
pst.setString(1, value[0]);
pst.setString(2, value[1]); //...
```

And finally, don't forget to close() the statement / connection too!

```
pst.close();
DatabaseConnection.ConnectDB().close(); ???
```